# Is it dangerous with a while(true) in silverlight?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight

I have this backgroundworker:

```
    MyBackgroundWorker.DoWork += ((sender, arg) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                client.GetkFailuresCompleted += ((s, e) =>
                {
                    int[] arr = JsonHelper.Deserialize<int[]>(e.Result);

                    int error = (int)((arr[0] / (double)arr[1]) * 100);

                    Debug.WriteLine("Error %: " + error);

                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            ErrorOverviewPointCollection.Clear();
                            ErrorOverviewPointCollection.Add(new Point(1, 100 - error));
                            ErrorOverviewPointCollection.Add(new Point(1, error));
                        });
                });
                client.GetFailuresAsync();

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        });
```

And as you see Im running it forever. I'm not implementing any stop/fail functions to stop the `BackgroundWorker`, but do I need to? If the user closes the browser the application should stop right?

The `DoWork` accesses a webservice that on completion updates a `ObservableCollection` that is databound to the silverlight application.

Comment: I would assume that closing the tab/browser would kill pretty much anything running in it. (In Chrome, each tab is a separate process).

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing this rather than using a timer?

Comment: you create a memory leak by registering the event each time ! [@Eren Ersönmez solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17987379/1425718) seems to be the most suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not executing as an out-of-browser application it's not dangerous. Bear in mind that all non-OOB silverlight applications are executed in a plugin, and once you close the browser application, the plugin closes, and terminates all code running in it.

That said, I am **not** saying it is dangerous code to execute in an OOB environment. But to be on the safe side you should test it to see if it remains alive after you close the OOB silverlight window.

However, best practice would be to replace the

```
while(true)
```

with

```
while(bApplicationIsAlive)
```

and set bApplicationIsAlive to false in the event handler of application's exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any disposable resources, it will be fine. If you do, then you should implement some sort of stop mechanism to gracefully stop the background work.

Also, with the async pattern, you really don't need that background worker. This is doable:

```
client.GetFailuresCompleted += (s, a) =>
{
    // do work...

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    client.GetFailuresAsync();
};
client.GetFailuresAsync();
```

This will avoid keeping a loop just to call the async method. Also, it has the advantage of delaying the wait period until *after* a response is handled, so calls don't overlap (in case the call and handling the response takes longer than 5 seconds).

And as Jon Skeet commented, you can achieve the same thing using a timer.